# what's the meaning of "BRI/2" token on user agent string

Tags: user-agent

i'm analyzing the user-agent string

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; BRI/2)`

using online services such http://user-agent-string.info/

None of this service recognize the token **BRI/2**

In this forum http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?280135-identifying-user-agent-string-tokens

an user says that this is *BRI Mobile, an add-on that has something to do with online banking*

I've searched for BRI Mobile and i've found that is an APP for iOs, Android, Windows PHONE... but now the question is: if i have, say, a windows phone with this app installed, and i use the Browser (not the BRI mobile app) to navigate on Internet, can my user-agent be altered by the BRI-Mobile APP?

Also, apart from the **BRI/2** token, the user-agent doesn't seem to have anything to do with a mobile device....

ty very much

Comment: This *appears* to be preventing some browsers from setting/receiving cookies properly

Comment: As since ever the user agent can contain anything, I would not care about its contents. The only way I can imagine rising issues with cookies is if the plugin alters the http headers. If a user installs such plugin and some websites won't work afterwards, I wouldn't care either. You could try to install [software](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bri.delivery.brimobile) associated (at your own risk) and look at the user agent again. Tho, I don't know what your goal is or do you actually have issues with the user agent?

Comment: We have a user who can't log in, and the only thing out of the ordinary is this in their user agent string.. I googled it and someone had a cookie issue with walmart cart with the same user agent string anomaly.  Above all I want to know WHAT this is, for security purposes.

Answer (score 4):

**BRI/2** token is come from [**Bing Toolbar**](http://www.bingtoolbar.com/en-US) & it's just available for Internet Explorer.

> The Bing Bar works with PCs running:
>
> Windows 7 or higher; Windows Vista; Windows XP with Service  Pack (SP)
>   3
>
> Internet Explorer 7 or above

and the other toolbars that you may want to know will add a string to the browser user agent:

- `Alexa Toolbar` Alexa
- `AskTbS-PV/5.15.12.33066` Ask
- `BRI/2` Bing
- `GTB7.4` Google

Comment: @ZachLeighton _Maybe for the earlier versions of Bing Toolbar they used it._

Answer (score 0):

The [Browser Exploitation Framework](https://github.com/beefproject/beef) detects all browser User Agent with "BRI" as Bing:

[modules/browser/detect_toolbars/command.js:](https://github.com/beefproject/beef/blob/master/modules/browser/detect_toolbars/command.js)

```
    var toolbar_ua = new Array (
            new Array (" Alexa Toolbar", " Alexa"),
            new Array (" AskTbS-PV", " Ask"),
            new Array (" BRI", " Bing"),
            new Array (" GTB", " Google"),
            new Array (" SU ", " Stumble Upon")
            )
```

This code seems to be the result of a trial and error process, as stated in the [author's blog](http://gcattani.co.vu/2013/02/detecting-browser-toolbars/):

> In January 2013 I began my involvement with the Browser Exploitation
>   Framework (BeEF) and the first assignement was the development of a
>   toolbar detection module. Since a preliminary web search highlighted
>   the lack of widespread information about the matter, **I got right into
>   hands-on testing**.